# Select multiple count in MySQL query with different where statements

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have two tables and I want to find different counts of rows after join them. My tables are:
[image: users table]

[image]

I want to select user's name and (I) the number of books that a user has (by ignoring status) and (II) the number of books that a user has with status 1. And all of these will be selected from, for example, the users who has "Doe" in his/her name. Is it possible? How can I get these results?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/102ce8/3

### Sample result:

(Name, Total Count, Specific Count)
John Doe, 3, 1
Jane Doe, 2, 1

Comment: `JOIN` and `COUNT(...)`. Perhaps with a soupçon of `SELECT` and the merest dash of `WHERE`.

Comment: well, a smidgen of case peut etre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tu.name,
       Count(ts.id),
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN status = 1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END)
FROM   tblUsers tu
       INNER JOIN tblStatus ts
         ON ts.id = tu.id
WHERE  tu.name LIKE '%doe%'
GROUP  BY tu.id
```

Answer (score 0):

u mean like this ?

SELECT nom,count(b.id_user),SUM(b.status) FROM user u,booking b WHERE u.id=b.id_user GROUP BY u.id

GROUP BY is your friend ;)

Answer (score 0):

This statement works with your SQL Fiddle:

```
SELECT 
  name,count(*),SUM(b.status) 

FROM users u

  INNER JOIN books b 
  ON u.id=b.user_id

GROUP BY u.id
```

If you want to see only the Doe Family add a WHERE clause like this:

```
SELECT 
  name,count(*),SUM(b.status) 

FROM users u

  INNER JOIN books b 
  ON u.id=b.user_id

WHERE  u.name LIKE '%Doe%'

GROUP BY u.id
```

If you want to use different values for your status column (e.g. 42 instead of 1) you should use the Conditional Aggregate count like this:

```
SELECT 
  name,count(*),SUM(CASE
             WHEN b.status = 1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) 

FROM users u

  INNER JOIN books b 
  ON u.id=b.user_id

WHERE  u.name LIKE '%Doe%'

GROUP BY u.id
```